# Issue with replacing part of string in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a method that reads a sql query as a string and needs to replace all '\' with '\\'. This is done to prevent \n and \r being processed as line breaks in the output.

```
private static String cleanTokenForCsv(String inputToken) {
        if (inputToken == null) {
            return "";
        }
        if (inputToken.length() == 0 || inputToken.contains(",") || inputToken.contains("\"")
                || inputToken.contains("\n") || inputToken.contains("\r")) {
            String replacedToken = inputToken.replace(",", ";");
            return String.format("\"%s\"", replacedToken.replace("\"", "\"\""));
        } else {
            return inputToken;
        }
    }
```

**Sample Input**

(\nSELECT\n a.population_id\n   ,a.empi_id\n\r  ,a.encounter_id\n   ,SPLIT_PART(MIN(a.service_date||'|'||a.norm_numeric_value),'|',2)::FLOAT as earliest_temperature\nFROM\n    ph_f_result a)

The expected output for the query would be along the lines of

`"(\nSELECT\n   a.population_id\n   ;a.empi_id\n\r  ;a.encounter_id\n   ;SPLIT_PART(MIN(a.service_date||'|'||a.norm_numeric_value);'|';2)::FLOAT as earliest_temperature\nFROM\n    ph_f_result a)"`

The entire query in one line with the line breaks intact

However, the output instead is

```
"(
SELECT
    a.population_id
    ;a.empi_id

    ;a.encounter_id
    ;SPLIT_PART(MIN(a.service_date||'|'||a.norm_numeric_value);'|';2)::FLOAT as earliest_temperature
FROM
    ph_f_result a)"
```

I also tried the following:

```
replacedToken = replacedToken.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

With Regex

```
replacedToken = replacedToken.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Edit: So I can get it to work if I add individual replace calls for \n and \r like below

```
replacedToken = replacedToken.replace("\n","\\n"); 
replacedToken = replacedToken.replace("\r", "\\r");
```

But I am looking for something more generic for all '\n' instances

Comment: `query.replaceAll("\n", "\\n")` etc.

Comment: There's also "\r" present in the input

Comment: Please show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that especially shows the precise characters in your string.

Comment: @AndyTurner There's no need for regular expressions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have carriage return and newline characters, not escaped r or n.

```
replacedToken = replacedToken.replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r");
```

This replaces all carriage return and newline characters with their escaped equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your goal is simply to convert characters `\r`, `\t` and `\n` in an input `String` to double-quoted two-character strings `"\\r"` and so on, so that printing the string does not result in newlines or tabs.

Note that the *character* `\n` does not really contain the *character* `\` at all. We simply agree to write `\n` to represent it. This should work:

```
   public static String escapeWhitespaceEscapes(String input) {
       return input
           .replace("\n", "\\n")
           .replace("\r", "\\r")
           .replace("\t", "\\t");
   }
```

But note that you will have to perform the reverse operation to get back the original string.